# Map varray of number(10) with hibernate and spring data jpa

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

If I have type in oracle declared like this :

```
CREATE TYPE group_ids AS VARRAY(1000000) OF NUMBER(10);
```

And a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE player_group_included
(
  group_id  NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  ids group_ids,

  CONSTRAINT fk_grIncl_group FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES player_group (id)
);
```

How can I map the `player_group_included` table to the Java entity with Hibernate/Spring Data JPA?

The obvious problem here is the ids column because it is using the custom Oracle type (array of numbers) and Hibernate cant recognize that by default.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/